# alert is showing null value as i am trying to get attribute value using iframe

Tags: jquery, dom

```
function getElement(){
var $link = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").children('a').first();
alert($link.attr('href'));
}
```

I am trying to get link address of node element from iframe but this is showing null value.

Comment: Is the iFrame of the same domain? Otherwise you will have a cross domain issue.

Comment: no iframe have other webaddress.

Comment: Then you cannot access the content of the iFrame.

Comment: Try $("#frametest").contents().find('html').html().find(".eod-topbox").children('a').first();

Comment: i done it i will post it after 8 hours thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to iframe with diffent domain. Read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: function getElement(){
     var $link = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").find('a');
     alert($link.attr('href'));
 }

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code for getting hyperlink :)

```
function getElement(){
  var $link = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").find('a');
  alert($link.attr('href'));
}
```